# Not able to use getter function as a prop in react native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

To explain this issue let's take an object with a property `value` which has it's own getter setter methods.

I'm using the `TextInput` component of react native.

When I pass the object as props for e.g

```
<TextInput {...myObj}/>
```

It should take the value property of the myObj & set it as the value of TextInput, but it doesn't work.

```
<TextInput value = {myObj.value}/>
```

Works fine.

I don't know why it's behaving like that.

Comment: can you post the object definition? looks like this property is not enumerable

Comment: This could be an interesting question, if you gave us more information